# How to Reset a Working folder VSS 2005

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

In Visual Source Safe 6.0, you could "reset" a working folder by setting it to a blank string.  This meant that the working folder would be determined by the working folder of the parent.

How do I do this in Visual Source Safe 2005?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This can't be done in the normal VSS 2005 "Set Working Folder" dialog.

However, if you **hold the shift key while invoking the "Set Working Folder" dialog**, it shows the old VSS 6.0 dialog.  Here you can reset the working folder by deleting the string and pressing OK.

Comment: how do you do it recursively?

Comment: to answer my own question, one way I found was to edit the ss.ini file that lives per user on the VSS server where the db resides

Answer (score 2):

If VS2005 still uses the .ini files you can delete the working folder record from the file and it will inherit it from the parent.

Comment: Working folders are stored on a per user, per project, per machine basis. They are stored in the <VSSDB>\users\<user>\ folder, in a file called ss.ini.  check here for more info:  http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2007/09/13/visual-sourcesafe-resetting-working-folders.aspx